# Can't get the msodbcsql package for Debian 10

Tags: pi-3b+, raspbian-buster, packages

I am currently attempting to set up my 3b+ (which runs on Raspbian Buster) to work with a database I have set up on Azure. I already downloaded the `pyodbc` package, but I can't seem to get the `msodbcsql17` package needed to work with SQL Server. I have been following the tutorial for Debian at

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15

but when I get to the line `sudo ACCEPT_EULA=Y apt-get install msodbcsql17`, this is the output I get from the terminal:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package msodbcsql17
```

Up until this point, I have not seen any indication that the previous lines have created errors. Has anybody else had this problem and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Ah, let me see.  It appears that the installation guy could not find the package "ms-odbc-sql-17.  I installed buster 2020feb05 release a couple of days ago, which automatically updated/upgraded then. I did sudo apt update and upgrade again just now and searched msodbcsql17 but still no luck.  My little raspbian experience tells me that buster desktop GUI menu add/remove option searching packages is often more comprehensive than its CLI sudo equivalent. So my quick conclusion is that buster does not like MS ODBC SQL packages.

Comment: Just now I searched pyodbc and found only 4 python3 modules. Usually a similar search gives me a couple of, up to, tens of pages even remotely relevant packages, but not this time. I guess pyodbc does not like MS ODBC, so I gave up.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at `https://packages.microsoft.com/debian/10/prod/pool/main/m/msodbcsql17/`, you will see that the only platform they support is AMD64. There are no packages for ARM.

BTW, don't just state that you [followed the tutoral](https://raspberrypi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2197/33476) next time you ask a question, cite the actual steps you took. The tutorial in question **cannot be followed** to the letter because you will end up installing packages for Debian 8, 9 and 10 simultaneously, which will certainly not work.

Comment: Looked through the other versions of msodbcsql and it looks like ARM is not supported across the board. Thanks for making this known to me. I'll be better about stating my steps next time.